# App Service: An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service

I am a little new to the Azure cloud, I have a Web API with App Service, from there I try to connect to another external web services, but when trying to connect I get an error:

> An error occurred while sending the request

I have given the virtual IP that is generated in the App Service to the administrators so that they can add it to their firewall, I have tried trying to consume other external services and there are no problems. Maybe I'm missing something additional?

I try to consume the external Web API normally, without the mentioned exception.

Comment: I hope it helps someone, the problem mentioned in the question was because all the outgoing IPs of the AppService must be added to the external firewall, not just the main IP. After requesting to do that, everything worked correctly!

Comment: Post your solution as an answer in detail for community help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it helps someone, the problem mentioned in the question was because all the outgoing IPs of the AppService must be added to the external firewall, not just the main IP. After requesting to do that, everything worked correctly!